# Why does my button not display in GUI (Python,TK)

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I am trying to create a simple GUI in Python to create buttons to access apps within my computer.

I am very new to Python & coding in general so bear with me..

I am getting 0 error messages when running the code but it just isn't displaying the button at the bottom. Here's what I have written out.

[Here's a screenshot of my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWtQV.png)

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os 

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#263D42")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1) 


openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10, 
                     pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42")

openFile.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What OS/python version are you using? Win 10 Python 3.9.5, it's showing the button at the very bottom.

Comment: I am using Win10 and running it on VisualStudio2019. Python3.7

Comment: Try removing the `frame.place(...)`. Does the button still not appear?

Comment: Still doesn't show...

Comment: It works fine in my Windows 10 running Python 3.9.6.

Comment: Not reproducible, try providing screenshots

Comment: Consider your screen size. The button is visible if the window fits in height.